# How to compute the sum of vectors

Tags: matrix, vectorization, octave

I know this question has been asked multiple times but that answer is not working for me. I want to compute summation like this

[image: equivation],

where `h(x) = X*theta`, `theta` is `n`x1 matrix and `X` is an `m`x`n` matrix. I tried to write in this way:

```
 f = @(z)(sum(X(z,:)*theta) - y(z))^2;
 v = sum(f([1:m])); % m is length of y
```

But it gave me this error:

```
error: for x^A, A must be a square matrix.  Use .^ for elementwise power.
error: called from
    computeCost>@<anonymous> at line 26 column 35
    computeCost at line 27 column 4
    ex1 at line 63 column 3
```

My equivalent for loop version is like this:

```
v = 0;
for i = 1:m
  v = v + (sum(X(i,:)*theta) - y(i))^2;
end
```

Please let me know how I can vectorize this loop.

Comment: The error message says "Use .^ for elementwise power." You're trying to compute matrix power here, which is not at all what your equation says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
v = 0;
for i = 1:m
  v = v + (sum(X(i,:)*theta) - y(i))^2;
end
```

is identical to this code:

```
v = 0;
for i = 1:m
  v = v + (X(i,:)*theta - y(i))^2;
end
```

(hint: `X(i,:)*theta` is a dot product, and returns a scalar).

To vectorize this, simply sum across the result:

```
v = (X*theta - y).^2;
v = sum(v);
```

This assumes that `y` is a column matrix (`m`x`1`). Note I used `.^` as indicated by your error message. This is the per-element power, rather than the matrix power `^`.

Comment: Hi It worked. And yes y is column vector I mentioned the same in my question. can you please explain what **X*theta - y** will return? because when I tried to the same simply I was getting dimension mis match error.

Comment: @vihangshah: `X*theta` is a column vector, because `X` has `n` columns and `theta` is a column vector with `n` elements (each element is the dot product of one row of `X` with `theta`). `y` is a vector with the same size, so the subtraction is element-wise, yielding another vector of the same size.